# Spring Batch and Intellij Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-batch

When using JdbcTemplate in Intellij the IDE is smart enough to recognize and validate SQL statements against a database schema.  I'm not able to get the same behavior from Intellij for JdbcCursorItemReader and the SQL used to create the Spring batch reader.  Is there a setting or 'trick' to get Intellij to become aware of the SQL statements like the example below - just like Intellij does for JdbcTemplate?

```
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(rosaDataSource);
    reader.setSql("SELECT email, id, created_on from users");
    reader.setRowMapper(new UserMapper());
    reader.setFetchSize(25);
    return reader;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a setting or 'trick' to get Intellij to become aware of the SQL statements like the example below - just like Intellij does for JdbcTemplate?

From the "Context Actions" popup menu, you can inject SQL language support in the query to get SQL specific completions, here is a screenshot:

[image: language]

[image: sql]

Comment: I have filed this as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-324535/SQL-code-highlighting-in-Spring-Batch to be supported out of the box

Comment: I don't think this is related to spring batch. This sql statement could have been passed to a JdbcTemplate, in which case you would also need to explicitly enable language support.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate already have built-in SQL mapping for all methods of JdbcTemplate.

Comment: OK I see. In that case, this feature could probably be part of the Spring Batch plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18505-spring-batch